# Queryset from two models for a single table

Tags: django, django-models, django-tables2

I have a list of parts (model 1) with prices (model 2). I want to display them in a django-tables2 table to get the historic prices of a part in a table:

**models.py:**

```
class Parts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=120, unique=True)

class Prices(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField("Price", decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    part = models.ForeignKey(Parts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**tables.py:**

```
class PriceHistoryTable(django_tables2.Table):
    price = django_tables2.Column(accessor="prices_list", verbose_name="Price",)
    date = django_tables2.Column(accessor="dates_list", verbose_name="Date",)

    class Meta:
        model = Parts
        sequence = ("date",  "price",)
```

I tried to create the tables from two lists as I thought the docs would suggest [here (list of dicts)](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/table-data.html#table-data) using these methods in the models:

```
def dates_list(self):
    return [{"date": d.date} for d in Prices.objects.filter(part_id = self.id)]

def prices_list(self):
    return [{"price": p.price} for p in Prices.objects.filter(part_id = self.id)]
```

But then I end up with a table in django-tables2 that contains the complete list of dates and prices in just one row.

How would a method look that creates a queryset for the prices and one for the dates, so I can use it for django-tables2?

***edit for the solution:***

**views.py**

```
class PartTable(SingleTableView):
    model = Parts
    template_name = "gap/parts_detail.html"
    table_class = PartPriceHistoryTable   
    queryset = Parts.objects.annotate(date=F("prices__date"),
                                      price=F("prices__price")).order_by('price', 'date')
```

**tables.py:**

```
class PriceHistoryTable(django_tables2.Table):
    price = django_tables2.Column(accessor="price", verbose_name="Price",)
    date = django_tables2.Column(accessor="date", verbose_name="Date",)

    class Meta:
        model = Parts
        sequence = ("date",  "price",)
```

models.py stays as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to annotate the value of date and price with queryset using [**`F()`** expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions), and access it through accessor(or not, just define the field name same as annotated variable) in the table. For example:

```
# table class
class PriceHistoryTable(django_tables2.Table):
    price = django_tables2.Column(accessor="price", verbose_name="Price",)
    date = django_tables2.Column(accessor="date", verbose_name="Date",)

    class Meta:
        model = Parts
        sequence = ("date",  "price",)

# example implementation
from django.db.models import F

queryset = Parts.objects.annotate(date=F('prices__date'), price=F('price__price')).order_by('parts', 'date')
table = PriceHistoryTable(queryset)

for item in table.as_values():
    print(item)

# view

class PartTable(SingleTableView):
    template_name = "gap/parts_detail.html"
    table_class = PartPriceHistoryTable
    table_pagination = {"per_page": 10}    
    queryset = Parts.objects.annotate(date=F("prices__date"), price=F("prices__price")).order_by('price', 'date')
```

Comment: how would you suggest I define the method in the `models.py`? I need a method `def price(self): ...` in the model to call it by accessor, right?

Comment: You do not need to do anything in model. The annotation should be done in views.py.

Comment: The table now shows the normal `Parts` model instead of the queryset: `class PartTable(SingleTableView):
    model = Parts
    template_name = "gap/parts_detail.html"
    queryset = Parts.objects.annotate(date=F("prices__date"), 
                                         price=F("prices__price")).order_by('price', 'date')

    table = PriceHistoryTable((queryset))`. In the meta class defined options like `exlucde = ('id',)` are ignored also.

Comment: can you share your view please?

Comment: I added my views.py.